# Override parent overflow - select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a plugin with my `select` html element, called http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/

The plugin works fine, however I'm facing some problems when using inside a `overflow: hidden`element, because it only shows partially the `select` option values.

The behaviour can be seen in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58zg3268/)** when clicking in **Seller**.

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="content form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3">Seller</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <select id="multiple-select" multiple>
                    <option>John</option>
                    <option>David</option>
                    <option>Muller</option>
                    <option>Maria</option>
                    <option>Britney</option>
                    <option>Mario</option>
                    <option>Fellaini</option>
                    <option>Mark</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.form` div has the css:

```
.form
{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

How do I fix this in order to see all elements?

Comment: You can try to add `overflow: auto;` to your `.form .content` in css. However it will add a scroll when you select seller.

Comment: Why you used `overflow: hidden` on `.form` ?

Comment: @AndriiPryimak can't do that.

Comment: @pedram In order to `.form` fill the entire space. I can't set a fixed height because it may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add this css `width:100%!important;` to `.ms-parent` class because it has taken inline css so overwrite it and remove`overflow:hidden` css to `.form` class.

I have updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/58zg3268/2/

```
.ms-parent {    
    width:100%!important;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where this is suppose to help. The problem persists.

Comment: @Linesofcode Try this answer, my answer is same. it works fine.

Comment: @ankitapatel I can't remove `overflow: hidden` because the goal is to full fill all the space using by the elements inside `form`.

Comment: @Linesofcode : your approach and markup is wrong, thats why its creating so much of mess. if your goal is to fill the DOM with form element, work around using width, height and padding. unnecessarily using `overflow` will just bite you every now and then as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow-y: auto` which can keep the same form height.

```
.form
{
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Add `max width: 100%` to prevent select box overflow and make all input same width.

```
.ms-parent {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rg432bak/)

Comment: Using `overflow-y: auto` creates a scrollbar that gives a ugly feel. https://s33.postimg.org/h5d12rlb3/no-title.png